# Find probability that twins are identical, given they are of same sex.

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

Identical twins are of same sex. For fraternal twins have $50$ - $50$ chance of same sex. Given that probability of fraternal twin is $1/3$ and identical twin is $2/3$. In a certain event Find probability that twins are identical, given that they are of same sex.

This problem came in my final exam, I used conditional probability to solve it but couldn't and left it. I am curious whats the answer and how to solve it. I have tried at home but dont know how do I do it. Any hint or guide will be useful

Comment: BAYES' THEOREM: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes%27_theorem

Comment: I have used this theorem. I am getting probability greater than $1$. Which is impossible

Comment: You have definitely made some mistakes. That is not possible.

Comment: Please add your attempt in the question(Bayes' theorem).

Comment: Yes it may be something simple to fix. Please add your attempt.